# C# equivalent of ccDebug in VB6

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

I am trying to convert VB6 code to c# and I ran into this code in VB6

```
#If ccDebug then
...
End If.
```

Please help me converting this code or doing this any other way.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks every one for the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to use

```
#if DEBUG
        //do special stuff 
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(ccDebug){
}
```

is the equivalent C# code.

Comment: He's got a # in front of the ccDebug, but StackOverflow thinks that's part of the markup, that's why it looks funny.

Comment: Ah didnt see that when I answered.

Comment: I just figured it out because I remembered seeing ccDebug before in some VB6 code for the same purpose before and then when I tried typing in #if it looked funny :).

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same if I understand your question correctly.

```
#if DEBUG
     ....
#endif
```

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) MSDN page for details.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a project wide constant, see this site for an example:

[Example](http://computerandscienceworld.blogspot.com/2008/11/tips-1.html)

You would be better off using

```
    #if DEBUG

    #endif
```